# Where Does KDE's Xsetup Live On FreeBSD?

Tags: xorg, kde, freebsd, x-server, kdm

I made the mistake of buying a keyboard with a backlight controlled by the scroll lock key, and in turn need to execute:

```
xset led 3
```

Every time the computer boots, just after the X server is started.  Since I'm using KDE I thought the best way to get it before the login screen would be to place it in Xsetup, however I can't locate it on my machine.

Does anyone know where Xsetup lives on FreeBSD 11?  Alternative approaches would also be welcome (please keep in mind `xset` must be run after the X server is started though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting X using KDM (`kdm4_enable="YES"` in /etc/rc.conf), then your Xsetup is, presumably, in /usr/local/share/config/kdm/Xsetup.

If you are running `startx` manually, just edit ~/.xinitrc and prepend `xset led 3` before `startkde` line.

Comment: Wouldn't `~/.xinitrc` be called after logging in?  I'm aiming for something at/before the login screen so I can see the keyboard to type in a password.  Edit: Marked this as correct because the `/usr/local/share/config/kdm/Xsetup` location was perfect - that executes as soon as the X server is started, just a moment before the login screen appears.  Thank you.